# I want pagination on the bottom, it is shown on the right side

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

The issue is that I am using pagination in my site, but pagination actually shows on footer.  But in my site it is shown on right side on my page.  Can you guys please help me?

You can see screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

---

Here is the code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">  
<thead>  

<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
else{
    $page = 1;
}
if($page ==''||$page == 1){
    $page1 = 0;
}
else{
    $page1 = ($page*10)-10;
}
$sql = 'select * from divlink ORDER BY Name ASC Limit '.$page1.', 12';
$data = $connect->query($sql);

//print_r($data ->fetch_all());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    $image  = $row['image'];
    $Name = $row[0];
        $Description = $row[1];
        $Price = $row[2];
        $ExpirtyDate = $row[3];
        $Facebook = $row[4];
        $Twitter = $row[5];
        $Telegram = $row[6];
        $Gmail = $row[7];
        $Youtube = $row[8];
        $Reddit = $row[9];
        $Meduim = $row[10];
        $Myetherwallet = $row[11];
        $neowallet = $row[12];
        $Bitcointalk = $row[13];
        $divicon = $row[14];
        $kyc = $row[15];
         $id = $row['id'];  
    $Rating = $row[17]; 

        //echo "<a href=''><div id='one' class='bordered' width='650px'><img src='{$Name}' class='imgss'/>{$Description}<p align='left'>{$id}</p><p align='right'>{$Price}</p><img src='{$Facebook}'width='20' height='20'><img src='{$Twitter}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/> <img src='{$Gmail}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/><img src='{$Youtube}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/><img src='{$Reddit}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/><img src='{$Meduim}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/><img src='{$Myetherwallet}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/><img src='{$neowallet}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/><img src='{$Bitcointalk}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/<img src='{$kyc}'  width='20' height='20' align='right'/>1<div id='circle'></div></a><input type='button' value='Like' name='click' class = 'block'>";
echo "<a href=''><div id='one' class='bordered' width='650px'><img src='{$image}' class='imgss'/><p align='left'><center>{$Name}<br>{$Description}<br>{$Price}</center></p><p align='right'>{$ExpirtyDate}</p><center><img src='{$Rating}'/></center><br><img src='{$Facebook}'width='20' height='20'align='left'><img src='{$Twitter}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/> <img src='{$Gmail}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/><img src='{$Youtube}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/><img src='{$Reddit}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/><img src='{$Meduim}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/><img src='{$Myetherwallet}'width='20' height='20' align='left'/><img src='{$neowallet}'width='20' height='20' align='left'/><img src='{$Bitcointalk}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/<img src='{$kyc}'  width='20' height='20' align='left'/>
        <form method='post' action=''><input type='hidden'  name='link_id' value='".$id."' /><input type='submit' name='like_button' value='Like' name='click' class = 'block'></form>

        ";



        echo "</tr>";
        echo"</div>";
               echo'</td>';



}
?> 
<?php
//pagination
$sql = 'select * from divlink';
$data = $connect->query($sql);
$record = $data->num_rows;
$records_pages = $record/12;
$records_pages = ceil($records_pages);
$prev = $page-1;
$next = $page+1;

echo'<ul class="pagination">';

if($prev >= 1) {

    echo '<li><a href="?page='.$prev.'">prev</a></li>';
}


if($records_pages >=2){
    for($r=1;$r<=$records_pages;$r++){
            $active = $r == $page ? 'class ="active"' : '';
        echo'<li><a href="?page='.$r.'">'.$r.'</a></li>';

}
}
if($next <= $records_pages && $records_pages >= 2) {

    echo '<li><a href="?page='.$next.'">next</a></li>';
}
if($page != $records_pages && $records_pages >= 5){
echo '<li><a href="?page='.$records_pages.'">Last</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';


?> 
    </section>
```

Comment: Give the paginations cointainer 100% width?

Comment: btw your script is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: can you please correct in my code if you think i am missing anything or anything goes wrong

Comment: You should google "avoid sql injection php"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the the boxes in a container like this:

```
<div class="container"> <a></a> <a></a> <a></a> </div>
```

And then under the div you can place your pagination

```
<div></div> <ul class="pagination"></ul>
```